# Генерация трех уникальных случайных чисел

Tags: java, случайные-числа

Нужно сгенерировать три уникальных случайных числа от одного до пяти. Уникальных - я имею ввиду неповторяющихся. К примеру:

```
1 2 3
5 3 2
3 2 5
```

Честно говоря, я просто не знаю как это воплотить на Java.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Set<Integer> generated = new HashSet<Integer>();
Random r = new Random();
while (generated.size() < 3) {
generated.add(r.nextInt(5) + 1);
}
```

Comment: Эклипс подчеркнул nextInt(5) и сказал что - "The method nextInt(int) is undefined for the type Random"

Comment: @MyNameIsWinner, проверяйте что у вас за тип такой `Random` что у него нет метода `nextInt`. Вот тут есть http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29 :)

Comment: Да, точно, это я сглупил, и класс назвал Random. Все работает!

Comment: Все, конечно, правильно. 

--

Ну и чего потом удивляться, когда при последовательном претворении в жизнь подобных методов программирования никаких гигабайт и гигагерц много уже не бывает.

--

@misha-nesterenko, Вы представляете объем ресурсов, который тащит за собой HashSet? И это ради массива из 3-х чисел?

Comment: @avp: да объём по идее не очень больший, массив bucket'ов и всё. Но вот алгоритмически можно и получше.

Comment: Ну HashSet может и в другом месте пригодиться. А генерировать... Взять случайное целое в диапазоне 0...maxvalue^3 и разделить на три числа.

Ну проверку можно организовать на отсутствие повторений (вероятность повторов-то ненулевая)

Comment: @VladD, конечно, для одной программки, вроде и немного. 

Но это все из серий:

"из пушки по воробьям", 

"разруха не в клозетах, а в головах"


и т.д.

А в итоге - 

"... посеешь характер, пожнешь судьбу".

Comment: @avp: Если этот код выполняется O(1) раз в качестве реакции на ввод пользователя, не имеет смысла выжимать из него последние микросекунды производительности, так как поддержка сложного кода сложна. А вот код, выполняющийся в цикле много миллионов раз, можно и нужно оптимизировать. Впрочем, лучше не надеяться на собственную интуицию, а провести профилирование: результаты профилирования иногда противоречат интуиции.

Comment: @VladD, видимо я (как, видимо, и всегда) неясно доношу свои мысли.

Дело не в **конкретном** коде, а в **общем** подходе к IT (в частности, к программированию).

Comment: @avp: Кажется, я вас понял. Да, подход «фигачь код, потом ногами запинаем» имеет место быть.

Answer (score 7):

Заранее составить все возможные варианты последовательностей трёх чисел от 1 до 5 (их всего-то 5 * 4 * 3 = 60) и генерировать случайное число от 0 до 59. Просто и быстро.

Comment: А что, хороший вариант. Почему никто не оценил? Предобработка рулит!

Comment: То есть как это никто? Как минимум четверо оценили. Остальные просто молодые, горячие еще, не все грабли своими лбами перепробовали...

Answer (score 3):

Ну это же в точности [выборка с резервуаром](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling) из Кнута (TAOCP 3.4.2S).

```
const int n = 5, k = 3;
Random r = <some global random instance>;
Integer[] result = new Integer[k];
for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
    result[i] = i + 1;

for (int i = k; i < n; i++)
{
    int j = r.nextInt(i + 1);
    if (j < k)
        result[j] = i + 1;
}
```