# Случайная генерация random int без повтора

Tags: java, массивы, случайные-числа

Необходимо прописать генерацию случайных 4х чисел из массива
Пока что код выглядит так

```
Random generator = new Random ();


        final int index1 = generator.nextInt ( imageIds1.length );
        final int randomImageId1 = imageIds1[ index1 ];

        final int index2 = generator.nextInt ( imageIds2.length );
        final int randomImageId2 = imageIds1[ index2 ];

        final int index3 = generator.nextInt ( imageIds3.length );
        final int randomImageId3 = imageIds1[ index3 ];

        final int index4 = generator.nextInt ( imageIds4.length );
        final int randomImageId4 = imageIds1[ index4 ];
```

Но проблема в том, что числа иногда повторяются. 
Как этого избежать?

Comment: используйте [множество Set](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/231275/177345) для запоминания сгенерированных чисел (оно хранит только уникальные значения)

Comment: Что такое `imageIds1.length`, `imageIds2.length`, `imageIds3.length` и т.д. Сколько у вас массивов? Почему диапазоны берутся из разных массивов?

Comment: @pavlofff думаю тут Set не подойдет,  так как при повторении допустим двух чисел в Set будет три числа, а необходимо сгенерировать 4 разных  числа

Comment: 1. Сгенерировать первое число. 2. Сгенерировать второе число, проверить не  совпадает ли с первым, если совпадает в цикле генерировать до тех пор, пока не будет не совпадающее число. 3. Сгенерировать третье, проверить на совпадение с первым и вторым, дальше все по аналогии

Comment: @Vennic: В случае, когда длина исходного рассматриваемый диапазона близка к количеству требуемых чисел, данный способ - дикая профанация, которую можно рассматривать разве что в юмористическом плане. Почему "студенты" постоянно пытаются делать это именно так, несмотря на наличие простых и доступных нормальных алгоритмов - одна из загадок мироздания. Уникальные случайные числа *никогда* не требуют генерации методом "проб и ошибок". Не делайте этого сами и другим не разрешайте.

Comment: @Vennic по ссылке в моем комментарии есть пример, как этот способ работает

Comment: @AnT вы правы, диапазон вполне можно брать из одного массива. Может подскажете, как использовать генерацию случайных чисел без проб и ошибок?

Comment: @pavlofff множество Set действительно работает, но я не могу понять, как "прикрутить" его к месту в моем массиве imageIds1[?? ]. 
С помощью синтаксиса for ("какая-то переменная") получается установить только одно место в массиве, а нужно сразу 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем, я пришел к ответу. Всем спасибо за помощь, хотя для новичка ваши ответы часто бывают сложнее поставленной задачи))
Оставлю код, может кому пригодится

```
//random numbers are 0,1,2,3...21
    ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Random r = new Random();
    while (numbers.size() < 4) {

        int random = r.nextInt(21);
        if (!numbers.contains(random)) {
            numbers.add(random);
        }
    }
    final int index1 = numbers.get (0);
    final int randomImageId1 = imageIds1[ index1 ];


    final int index2 = numbers.get (1);
    final int randomImageId2 = imageIds1[ index2 ];


    final int index3 = numbers.get (2);
    final int randomImageId3 = imageIds1[ index3 ];

    final int index4 = numbers.get (3);
    final int randomImageId4 = imageIds1[ index4 ];
```

Answer (score 2):

Если вам необходимо сгенерировать некоторое количество `K` равновероятно выбранных неповторяющихся случайных целых чисел в заданном диапазоне `[0, N)` и при этом вам разрешается использовать дополнительную поисковую структуру данных для запоминания уже сгенерированных чисел, то алгоритм, который не делает итераций "проб и ошибок" выглядит так

```
S - множество уже сгенерированных чисел, изначально пустое
for i = N - K to N - 1
  r = random из диапазона [0, i]
  if (r не принадлежит S)
    новое число - r
    добавляем r в S
  else
    новое число - i
    добавляем i в S
```

Такой алгоритм выбирает каждое число с равной вероятностью, но не обязательно выдает числа на выход в полностью случайном порядке. Если и порядок нужен случайный, то выход алгоритма следует еще дополнительно случайно перетасовать.